# fglrx doesn't seem to be installed

Tags: graphics, fglrx, hybrid-graphics

Hello everybody,
    here's my problem. I'm trying to install fglrx to my ubuntu 14.04, I've tried following [this](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Problems_Starting_Xserver), the problem is after the installation of the .deb file, when I'm supposed to use this command`sudo amdconfig --initial -f` it says that the command wasn't found (happens the same to `fglrxinfo`); so I tried follow the "amdconfig not found after installation" on the same link mentioned above, but when I use `sudo update-alternatives --set gl_conf /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf` it says "error: no alternatives for gl_conf".
    I've tried everything I can, my computer is a HP G62-B10SP, it has both Intel and AMD graphic board. I'm new to ubuntu and I'm trying to play 3d games with it; I'm not sure if it is really better to have fglrx or the open source drive, so, I want to know if it is better to have fglrx and, if it is, how to fix my problem.
Thanks for everything in advance.
Ps. I don't know if I'm suppose to have it, but it seems like I don't have the xorg.conf file.

Comment: I thought the command was `aticonfig` not `amdconfig`?

Comment: I've Seen both, and tried both.

Answer (score 0):

To install or update proprietary drivers, just open up `Additional Drivers` under `Software and Updates` in`Settings`. This will let you download and install either `flgrx` or `flgrx-updates`.

Comment: It is already marked as flgrx-updates, but it still doesn't seems to be working... I also tried the flgrx.